# Trying to stream RTSP to Youtube via VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, youtube, rtsp

Kinda of a noob at ffmpeg but familiar enough with VLC.

Trying to convert and stream RTSP to youtube live and having no luck.

What am I missing?

I know a lot of input in the empty fields and therein lies my problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you want an answer involving `ffmpeg`? Or is this just about VLC?

Comment: What is your specific question? Do you need to know how to configure it? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428837/broadcasting-to-youtube-live-via-rtmp-using-vlc-from-terminal — and perhaps you want to have a look at https://obsproject.com/ as an alternative.

Comment: @llogan and @ slhck -- thanks.Thank you for not stoning me and calling me an idiot - I am grateful for your good humor as a non regular forum poster. 

I have tried OBSP and got stuck in the same spot.

I,d love to be able to cli the entire process with ffmpeg if I can -- but really mostly needing to find a solution.

*(Weather station, florida, hurrricane, live footage)* 

VLC seemed like the easy answer and then when I got frustrated I figured I'd ask here.  

Thanks again for humoring me. Epic stormm and 15 cameras poyentiskky [gulp]

Sent from my iPad

Comment: @slhck [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428837/broadcasting-to-youtube-live-via-rtmp-using-vlc-from-terminal) _italic_ **bold**  must be the answer

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Did that link solve your problem? (That is, could you use `cvlc` to achieve that?) As for OBS, you have a very specific guide here: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-live-stream-on-youtube-with-obs/ — ideally, in your question, please state what exactly you have tried already and where you got stuck.

Comment: @slchk it looks like all the direction I need (what I now realize is I needed clear instruction, more than a specific question) but haven't been able to deploy it yet. 2 more hours. Sorry for the un-clear question, And thank you for the generosity of spirit in responding....

Comment: No problem. If you are getting stuck somewhere, please [edit] your post and add some screenshots showing us what you did, what guide you followed, and where exactly you are having issues.